# Regex right match url with DOT at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I have right regex to find urls in text, but one thing i can't solve.
If url ends with DOT - this dot matches as part of url.

This is my pattern:

```
/(^|[\?\s])(www\.[^\? ]+\/[^\/ ]*\?[^\? ]+|www\.[^\? ]+)/g
```

For sample, text is `'The url is www.domain.com. Second is wiki.org.'`

Urls last dot is not part of url, but regex replace it too.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DKNat/11/)

Comment: Post your current regex so we can see what you are trying?

Comment: a good read: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: @thg435 and that's why using regular expressions for URLs is a bad idea.

Comment: That regex is not good at all. Why should this `Whats up?www.domain.com` match and not `I'm good, thanks!www.domain.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to require a non-punctuation character as the last character:

```
/(^|[?\s])(www\.[^? ]+\/[^/ ]*\?[^? ]*[^?.,! ]|www\.[^? ]*[^?.,! ])/g
```

Note that I removed some of your backslash, because they were not necessary.

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qUkfN/)

However, this is still by for not a robust URL pattern. So, why reinvent the wheel instead of just using [some established URL pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)?

Comment: Well, this fixes dots, but not things like "google.com, yahoo.com!".

Comment: @thg435 that's true actually... I fixed that bit, but the main point of my answer is actually that this solution isn't robust either, and the OP should resort to existing solutions.

Comment: Yes, i was add it in another feed, its easy

Comment: Why reinvent... good question :) Some of regex not convenient coz detect A-Z and not cyrilic, some use list of TLDs, not convenient too.. I love use self made, but regex new for me

Comment: One thing really not ready, it where url contain PORT. Like www.domain.net:8080